# How to link OpenSSL in CMake propely

Tags: cmake, openssl, linker

I'm trying to link OpenSSL library to my project using CMake.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
All I do is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

project (test)

add_executable(test test.cpp)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)


target_link_libraries(
    test PRIVATE OPENSSL::SSL
)
```

And I get an error **Target "test" links to target "OPENSSL::SSL" but the target was not found.** 
I had installed OpenSSL with "sudo apt install libssl-dev" so it must be installed.
What can I do here?

Comment: The module name is `OpenSSL::SSL` . Case matters. The other modules, btw, are `OpenSSL::Crypto` for libcrypto, and `OpenSSL::applink` if needed. There are other options. See [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html) for more information.